# Consume WCF service reference in Webrole application

Tags: cloud, azure

I have developed a cloud application with one Webrole and a WCF role. My WCF service will act as model and gets me the data from the database. I am able get the Service Referece of my WCF service in my webrole when it running either in localhost or from IIS.

But when i run my webrole and wcf service in Dev Fabric, i am unable to take the service reference which is running on dev fabric with the url **http://127.0.0.1/TestService.svc**.

The web.config i am using in webrole is,

Can somebody share me some information, how can i take the service reference of a WCF service which is running in dev fabric from a web role?

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the web.config, but it appears you didn't include it in your original post. Regardless: you are missing the port number on your URI.